# Sanitizing a Date

Tags: php, sanitization

I am using a javascript date picker that allows the user to select a date. However, I would like to also sanitize the posted date data before entering into the database. I am not seeing any sanitize filter here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

What would be the best method to sanitize a date before entering into a database?

This would be the original value from the post:

```
$datepick = $_POST['date'];
// wich is 04/12/2014
```

Then I convert it for the database:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datepick));
```

Thanks!

Comment: What date format does the date picker use? Also, what format does your database expect?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Hello, I just update the post to reflect your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your date is like "03/02/2014" then you can simply clean your variable by regexp:

```
$date = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $_POST['date']);
```

This allows only digits (0-9) and fwd slash (/).

Comment: Hello, I just updated the post to show what I am currently doing with the date and the value.

Comment: I think this will work well for my needs. I'll test it out. Thanks

Comment: @MagentoMan I just updated by answer based on your changes. If it works - mark it as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to ask you to update your post to that answer so I could :)

Answer (score 5):

Formatting the date sanitizes it, because:

1. If the formatter succeeds, then it will only be a date, with syntax controlled by the format string.
2. If it fails, then FALSE is returned.

This is true of:

```
DateTime::format
DateTimeImmutable::format
DateTimeInterface::format
date_format()
Date($format, $date_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression can be used to support both 12/12/2016 and 12-12-1993 formats.

```
filter_var (preg_replace("([^0-9/] | [^0-9-])","",htmlentities($input)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest is:

```
$date = trim($_GET['date'])==='' ? false : new DateTime(trim($_GET['date']));
if($date) $date= $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

With the above $date will either be a sanitised date string or false if it failed.