# variable on php query with getJson

Tags: javascript, php, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

I recently asked for a problem, but I still with troubles on my site:

I have a php with a query to a SQL server, gettin a var from html, but i need to know if I have to send the var with some method to the php? i mean, the json in ok, I write the date on a text field, but it doesn get the php result. I need to insert some button to call it after insert the date or it should be automatic just inserting the var?

this is the php. I put the variable on the last declaration on WHERE.

```html
<?php
function getArraySQL(){
$dsn = "prueba";
$connect = odbc_connect( $dsn, '', '' );
$shiftdate = $_GET["shiftdate"];  //one of the variables that i need to input on my query
$query = "  SELECT hist_statusevents.reason, Sum(hist_statusevents.duration/3600) AS 'Duracion'
FROM hist_statusevents, hist_eqmtlist, hist_exproot
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex AND hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex AND hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid AND (hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid='SVEDALA') AND hist_statusevents.category In ('2') AND hist_exproot.ddmmyy =$shiftdate
GROUP BY hist_statusevents.reason
ORDER BY Duracion DESC";

if(!$rs = odbc_exec($connect, $query)) die();

$rawdata = array();

$i=0;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{
$rawdata[$i] = $row;
$i++;
}
odbc_close( $connect );
return $rawdata;
}
$myarray = getArraySQL();
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

On the other side, my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Report Monitor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
  <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="main container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="post col-md-12">
        <div class="miga-de-pan">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Inicio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Inputs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">Reports</li>
          </ol>
        </div>

      </section>

      <section class="post col-md-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha del Turno" id="shiftdate">

      </section>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="clas col-md-4">
          <h4>Indicador 1</h4>

          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              shiftdate = $('#shiftdate').val()
              $.getJSON('dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php', {
                shiftdate: shiftdate
              }, function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                  $('ul').append('<li Reason="' + val.reason + '">' + val.reason + '-' + val.Duracion + '</li>');
                });
              });
            });
          </script>
          <ul></ul>

        </div>
        <div class="clas col-md-4">
          <h4>Indicador 2</h4> 
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $.getJSON('dbquery.php', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                  $('ul2').append('<li Reason="' + val.reason + '">' + val.reason + '-' + val.Duracion + '</li>');
                });
              });
            });
          </script>
          <ul2></ul2>

        </div>
        <div class="clas col-md-4">
          <h4>Indicador 3</h4> 
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $.getJSON('dbquery.php', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                  $('ul3').append('<li Reason="' + val.reason + '">' + val.reason + '-' + val.Duracion + '</li>');
                });
              });
            });
          </script>
          <ul3></ul3>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </section>
  <footer></footer>



</body>

</html>
```

The first json function is the one where im trying to insert the parameter shifdate.

And the shifdate is inserted on the section class:

```
      <section class="post col-md-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha del Turno" id="shiftdate">

      </section>
```

additionally the php gives me this result on chrome:

```
Notice: Undefined index: shiftdate in C:\xampp\htdocs\byp1\dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php on line 5

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor., SQL state 01000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\byp1\dbquery_plus_shiftdate.php on line 12
```

but if i exclude `$shiftdate = $_GET["shiftdate"];` and the part where i give it to the query i don have any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you need to consider.

Connecting every time you need data is a really bad idea. This will make your life harder maintaining the code. I recommend using a database wrapper.

Also, In your query, you should be using a sanitized version of the $_GET['variable'].

Example: [Sanitizing a Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039207/sanitizing-a-date)

And what would happen if you didn't have the $_GET['variable'] in question? More errors. You can use

```
if (isset($_GET['variable'])) 
    $var = $_GET['variable'];
else 
    $variable = "some default";
```

I would recommend using odbc_prepare and odbc_execute for your queries. It is safer and makes your code more readable.

[odbc_prepare on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php)

Comment: Maybe I should redefine the way Im taking this project. The thing is, my enterprise have this excel solution that connects to the sql server to generate a report, and my boss ask me to develop a solution to migrate from excel to any other application that would allow to make a dashboard and show the KPI. Considering I´m not informatic, i began to investigate and decide that i must connect to the database via php odbc and print the results of the querys on html, at this point all i have is what you see, bu according what you told me, maybe i should investigate another way to think this solution

Comment: and there are a lot of querys so, probably i will have some trouble trying to connect every time...


by the way, is incredible the ammount of aknowledge that i have adquired trying to develop this solution, even when i haven get nothing functional yet...

Comment: Just use a class for connecting with your database. it's very easy to re-use code and maintain it properly.

Comment: i´m sorry, but what do you mean with a class?

Comment: Even when the other answer solve a punctual issue, you explain to me te basics of my problem

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will investigate

Answer (score 1):

The problem is only on this line
`$shiftdate = $_GET["shiftdate"];`

You get the error, because $_GET doesn't have a shiftdate key.

For a start, change this

```
<section class="post col-md-12">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha del Turno" id="shiftdate">
</section>
```

to this

```
<form method="GET" class="post col-md-12">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha del Turno" id="shiftdate" name="shiftdate">
</form>
```

Comment: But when i do that, the navigator gives to me this error:

http://localhost:8080/byp1/GET?shiftdate=11-11-01

Comment: My mistake, i still getting used to Stack over Flow.  Thanks for your patiente.


Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8

Comment: and the form code generates the GET?shifdate on my url

Comment: Sorry, the action attribute should be replaced with method="GET". Sorry about that!